# shell split a string using variable delimiters

Tags: shell, split

My problem is quite simple but I do not manage to solve it:

I have a string that looks like this:

```
-3445.51692 -7177.16664 -9945.11057
```

the tricky part is that there could be zero or more withe space between each number and the latter can be either negative or positive, meaning that the string could also be like:

```
-3445.51692-7177.16664  -9945.11057
```

or

```
-3445.51692 7177.16664-9945.11057
```

(in case of a positive value there is at least one white space that precedes)

and I would like to split this string into three variables that contains each number, e.g.:

```
a=-3445.51692
b=-7177.16664
c=-9945.11057
```

Thus, I wanted to use something like

```
IFS=' -' read -a array <<< "$string"
```

but I don't know how to specify "zero or more white space". And using "-" as a delimiter removes it from the final result, while I want to keep the sign.

Any ideas ?

Comment: does it have to be 'read'? Can you not for example use sed to parse the string?

Comment: You are right, sed is more appropriate here, like suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonicalize the input before you do the IFS splitting, i.e. any minus gets a space prepended:

```
canonicalized_string=$(echo "$string" | sed 's/-/ -/g')
set -- $canonicalized_string   # No need to mess with IFS.
a=$1
b=$2
c=$3
```

This assumes exactly 3 numbers. In super-compact form:

```
set -- $(echo "$string" | sed 's/-/ -/g')
a=$1 b=$2 c=$3
```

Comment: Thanks :) ! I've got one question though, how does the "set" command replace the IFS method ? I mean according to what does it split the string ?

Comment: @Goujon The POSIX shell specification says that the default value for IFS is <space><tab><newline>. `set` doesn't do any splitting; it's simply the shell that performs word splitting according to IFS for any command.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `sed` to add a space infront of every `-`, Something like:

```
echo $string | sed 's/-/ -/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read -a` by injecting a space first:

```
s='-3445.51692-7177.16664  -9945.11057'
IFS=' ' read -ra arr <<< "${s//-/ -}"
printf "[%s]\n" "${arr[@]}"
[-3445.51692]
[-7177.16664]
[-9945.11057]
```